# Check if mobile number is valid in Rotterdam

Tags: cellphones, netherlands, mobile-operators, rotterdam

I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask this, so sorry in advance if not. I am making a mobile application, where users can register with their mobile phone numbers.

The app is for Rotterdam only. I need to validate the form of the mobile number entered, but I do not know how a mobile number should look in Rotterdam for it to be valid.

I have a clue that it should start with +31 than 6 for Rotterdam and it should be followed by 7 digits.

Can you help me guys?

Comment: This is off topic as it has nothing to do with travel.  But the *6* prefix is for *all mobile phones in all of the Netherlands.*  The numbers are completely portable (they're *mobile,* after all), so they're not bound to a particular locality.  After the 6, there should be eight additional digits, not seven.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_Netherlands.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If it's to avoid honest mistakes and half-hearted attempts by curious users, then a warning would go a long way, checking the number is a valid Dutch number and/or requiring a valid postcode could help too. But if you want to defeat spammers and others who are deliberately trying to gain access, then much bigger players than yourself have tried and failed. There are apps to fake GPS reading, etc. and no bullet-proof method to know where a user is, certainly not based only on the number and without special access to the network's infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

All Dutch telephone numbers have 10 digits, starting with the 0, (which falls away when you add the international number.)

So for a Dutch mobile number you will have +31 6 ABC DE FGH. Whereby the letters stand for the digits of the telephone number.

The 6 is for a Dutch mobile number, a Rotterdam land line number starts with 010, (so +31 10 AB CD EFG).

Made up numbers can be excluded by tests, sites have ways to check that you use a real number, like sending a text message asking you to reply or do something on the app.
Checking that the phone is in Rotterdam and nowhere else is much harder.
All Dutch mobile numbers and many foreign numbers can be in Rotterdam.
If it is possible to get a location from the network, which they can do if the phone is set to allow it, you could use that. Or you could ask the phone owner to enter extra details which show (as far as you can confirm) he is in the city.

PS, the spaces I put in the numbers are for reading only, while dialing you keep the numbers following, no spaces.

Comment: Yeah the right thing to do here, as Willeke notes, is to use a service to send a text message to the number and validate it with a code. An API like Twitter's [Digits](https://get.digits.com/) or Twilio can help you with this. (Twilio also has a [lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) that can validate the structure of the number, but doesn't confirm ownership.)

Comment: Today I was in Rotterdam, in the group there we had people from the north and north west of the country and out of Antwerp, Belgium. You will need to decide whether to exclude any of them. The country is quite small and people do often visit across the country and regularly from abroad.

Comment: By the way, this is not a rare occurance, we meet regularly and we are surely not the only group like this. And then there are students and people working who commute long distances, weekly or even daily.